# Describe a function $C^1$

Tags: functions, planar-graphs

How do I describe the following function

$f(-1)=f(1)=0$ $f^{\prime}(x) =1$ on $[a,b]^{c}$ and $f \in C^{1}[-1,1]$. In blue, I know $f(x) = x+1$ on $[-1,a)$ and $f(x) = x-1$ on $(b,1]$. I can't get the green part. The design is not so cool, but that's the idea, a function that is $C^{1}[-1,1]$, so there has to be a little curve coming out of $a$ and a little curve arriving at $b$, the path can be in any way as long as it is continuous.

[image]

Comment: There is a function of the form $\alpha (x-a)^{2}+\beta (x-a)+\gamma (x-b)^{2}+\delta (x-b)+\eta$ which meets the requirements.

Comment: Great. Could you tell me the values of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$?

Comment: You can find these values by requiring continuity of $f$ and $f'$ at the points $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I'm plotting this function in Geogegra, but it's not the one I want. It's not a parabola

Comment: @student91 I'm plotting this function in Geogegra, but it's not the one I want

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28x-%281%2F2%29%29%5E%7B2%7D+%2B+%28x-%281%2F2%29%29+%2B+%28x-%282%2F3%29%29%5E%7B2%7D+%2B+%28x-%282%2F3%29%29+to+-1%2F2+%3C+x+%3C+1%2F2

Comment: Indeed, the function suggested by @geetha290krm does not seem to work, as $f'(a)=f'(b)=1$ gives $\alpha=-\gamma$, and you end up with a linear equation, which will not work. Instead, you could try a function of the form $f(x)=\alpha(x-a)^3+\beta(x-a)^2+x+1$. It already satisfies $f'(a)=1$ and $f(a)=1+a$, and you have to choose $\alpha,\beta$ such that $f'(b)=1$ and $f(b)=b-1$.

Comment: @student91 $f(x) = \alpha(x-a)^{3} + \beta(x-b)^{2} + x+1$ did you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @student91 $f(x)=\alpha(x-a)^3+\beta(x-b)^2+x+1$

No, I actually meant what I wrote.

To solve this problem, there are several things you can do:

You could try a polynomial function of minimal degree. First, you can try a function of the form $\alpha x+\beta$, but you will soon see this does not work. Then, you could look at something of the form $\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma$, which is essentially what geetha suggested. Unfortunately, we found that this does not work either. Then, we can look at a function of the form $\alpha x^3+\beta x^2+\gamma x+\delta$. But to make things easier, we instead look at $$\alpha (x-a)^3+\beta (x-a)^2+\gamma (x-a)+\delta.$$

Now $f(a)=1+a$ gives $\delta=1+a$ and $f'(a)=1$ gives $\gamma=1$, so we arrive at $$f(x) = \alpha (x-a)^3+\beta (x-a)^2+x+1.$$

(Note how the $a$ in the $\delta$ term and the $a$ in the $\gamma$ term cancel each other out)

Solving the equations $f'(b)=1$ and $f(b)=b-1$ gives $3\alpha(b-a)^2+2\beta(b-a)=0$ and $\alpha(b-a)^3+\beta(b-a)^2+2=0$ respectively, which you can then solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. It gives $$f(x)=4\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^3-6\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^2+x+1$$

Alternatively, you could do something with [smooth transition functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions) or [smoothstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) functions. If $g(x)$ is any sufficiently smooth function such that $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq0$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x\geq1$, you could take $$f(x)=(x-1)g\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right) + (x+1)\left(1-g\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Very good. I loved. Thank you very much. Got it all.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+4*%28x%2B0.5%29%5E3+-6*%28x%2B0.5%29%5E2+%2B+x%2B+1++++from+-0.5+to+0.5 It was very beautiful for $a=-0.5$ and $b = 0.5$. :)